# C# Selenium Tests on CodeFresh not loading test file

Tags: c#, selenium, yaml, codefresh

We have a batch of C#/Selenium/xUnit tests running in a CodeFresh pipeline.
They all work well apart from 2, these try to upload test files.
This works well when run local the code is

```
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Data\image1.jpg");
        addFile.SendKeys(filePath);
```

The test files are stored here [image] and they are set to 'Copy always'
So they deploy ok but they do not seem to be making their way up to the build yaml file.
Currently the steps are
clone
build
push_image

The clone step is pulling from the correct repo and the data files exists there.
Any ideas please?

Kev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it.
Move the files to the project root and changed code -

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"image1.jpg");
addFile.SendKeys(filePath);
```

Now all good, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
    public static string GetBasePath
    {
        get
        {
            var basePath =
                System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName((System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
            basePath = basePath.Substring(0, basePath.Length - 10);
            return basePath;
        }
    }

var filePath = Path.Combine(GetBasePath, @"Data\image1.jpg");
```

Comment: well that sucks. I thought that would work. I have had a similar issue with cloudbees. If you have it set to Cop Always, that should copy to bin\debug. Does the file show up in that directory after you build the solution?